# How to write a Cocoa OpenGL app in C++?

Tags: c++, cocoa, opengl

I'm writing an application that needs to use OpenGL, on the Mac, in C++.

Is there anyway I can get Cocoa to just give me an OpenGL context and let me do my work in C++? (I want my app to run on both Mac OS X and iPHone; but all the GUI is in OpenGL, I just need a OpenGL context).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot escape a minimal amount of objective-C code. However, if you rename the objective C files to .mm files, the objective C code will be able to call c++ class methods. This means you can hook the -drawRect (and other relevent NSOpenGLView messages) to your c++ OpenGL implementation. The NSOpenGLView has a -makeCurrent method that you can call outside of drawRect to ensure that the correct OpenGL context is active.

Your c++ code can then simply call gl functions as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [NSOpenGLView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/). In `drawRect:` in your subclass, you can access the view's context and call your OpenGL code.