# setup opengl on mac os x

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I want to start learning Opengl and making some basic 3d applications on the Mac os x operating system.

I use C++, should i use command line or Cocoa application?
is the command line means it will makes non GUI and the coca framework will make a GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Cocoa as going to full screen would mean you need to take away the control from the desktop/window manager.  I would think you could write your programs more easily by being able to look at both the source code and the OpenGL program at the same time (this is much easier if you use a window to launch the OpenGL program).

Look at [Cocoa OpenGL app in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102151/how-to-write-a-cocoa-opengl-app-in-c) (found using google to search the web) for ideas how to get an OpenGL context.

Comment: Thank you, you know how can i add gltools library to xcode 4?

Answer (score 1):

[GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) is a cross-platform C library for creating an OpenGL window and handling input.

The first chapter of the [user guide](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/glfw/docs/UsersGuide.pdf) gives a minimal example of how to use it.

It can be used with XCode, but if you want to compile something with it via the command line, use:

```
g++ *.cc -lglfw -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit
```

You will still need to install XCode and the command line tools, of course.